# YII->CRUD не работает DELETE

Tags: yii

С помощью crud genirator был создан функционал для работы с таблицей. Но не работает удаление ни в меню

```
    array('label'=>'Удалить категорию', 'url'=>"#", 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->c_id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?','csrf'=>true)),
```

ни в таблице крестик

[image]

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
}
```

Comment: покажите код `actinDelete`

Comment: @Python_Pro добавила в описание вопроса

Comment: А когда на крестик пытаетесь нажать, он какую ссылку вам показывает?

Comment: @Python_Pro /delete/id-удаляемой записи

Comment: Оффтоп:Как по -русски сказать Yii и по английски...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правде говоря, если Вы используете компонент urlManager, то ссылка должна выглядеть примерно так:
.../delete/id/{id_nr}
Попробуйте в linkOptions в параметре 'submit' поменять это:

```
array('delete','id'=>$model->c_id)
```

на это:

```
array('delete/id/'.$model->c_id)
```

Comment: при таком раскладе никакой реакции на нажатие "удалить" не происходит

Comment: В предусмотренном для этих кнопок классе CButtonColumn имеются параметры для удобной конфигурации кнопок view, delete и update: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail. Почему не хотите воспользоваться ими?

Answer (score 1):

`400`-я ошибка означает что у вас в `action` падает аргументов меньше чем там указано. Попробуйте поискать ошибку в `protected/config/main.php` и сделать (временно) так:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(),
),
```

А потом - перейти по такому `URL`: `http://mysite/kakojto_kontrioller/delete?id=1`

или (ели у вас нету `.haccess`'а)

```
http://mysite/index.php?r=kakojto_kontrioller/delete&id=1
```

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
            
   'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),
  ),



Если 'showScriptName'=>false поставить, то возникают проблемы с переходом на страницы, без index.php не переходит. А что должно быть написано в.haccess'е?

Comment: AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

# если директория или файл существуют, использовать их напрямую
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# иначе отправлять запрос на файл index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: @Python_Pro проблема перехода по страницам не устранилась.
В .haccess добавила строчки по вашему совету, а в main.php добавила строку 
'showScriptName'=>false

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это из-за того, что Gii генерит контроллер с фильтром, в котором указано 'postOnly + delete' - закомментируй данную строку, и будет тебе счастье.

```
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }
```